# C# Socket Programming: how to identify client by name not by IP

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new to socket Programming. I'm developing a Client-Server Communication Program and having difficulty with Showing Client Name instead of IP address when client gets connected to the Server. Can anyone suggest me a good approach? How I can do that? I need that IP as well for further communication.
Here's my Client Side Code:

```
mTcpClient = new TcpClient();
mTcpClient.BeginConnect(ipa, nPort, onCompleteConnect, mTcpClient);
```

And that onCompleteConnect function:

```
void onCompleteConnect(IAsyncResult iar)
    {

        TcpClient tcpc;

        try
        {
            tcpc = (TcpClient)iar.AsyncState;
            tcpc.EndConnect(iar);
            mRx = new byte[512];
            tcpc.GetStream().BeginRead(mRx, 0, mRx.Length, onCompleteReadFromServerStream, tcpc);

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to send Client Name as Well and Receive at Server Side. What should I do?

Comment: Since you already have the name when you connect use the string in the connect statement.  A simple trick is to make a custom class the inherits the TcpClient and add a property called ClientName. Or make a state object (like in the msdn samples) and put the client name as a property in the state object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` to read Strings.

**Example**

Client:

```
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(mTcpClient.GetStream());
sW.AutoFlush = true;

// Send the username
sW.WriteLine(Environment.UserName);
```

Server:

```
StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(mTcpClient.GetStream());

// Read the username (waiting for the client to use WriteLine())
String username = sR.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Send the `Environment.UserName` property from the client to the server.

Comment: Thanks, But I have the username in program settings. I want to send that username to server when it gets connected to the server.


this line on server gives me the IP of the client

new ClientNode(tclient, new byte[512], new byte[512], tclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())));

Comment: Using that byte buffer, you can fill the first 4 bytes as a header that says "user" and the next 508 bytes to send the username. Because the username most likely wont be 508 bytes exactly you will need to add trailing null bytes to the buffer and then send it from the client. The server should read the first 4 header bytes and then read the next 508 bytes as the username. The server should remove the trailing null bytes added to the buffer and then you should have the username.